# How to use HtmlAgilityPack for context aware parsing of all of the inner text between specific nodes

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have the following 5 snippets of Html passed in from an external API that I have no control over the existing formatting.

I need to split the HTML Into a response class with the following structure

```
public class Resposne{
    bool isLeading {get;set;} //set to true only if there was an input detected after the last response was read
    int ResponseId {get;set;}
    string LeadingStem {get;set;}
    bool isLagging{get;set;} //set to true only if it's the final text node, and has no input after it
}
```

The expected output is listed beneath each HtmlBlock (please forgive the pseudocode for those}

HTML 1:

```
    <tr style="height: 179px;">
        <td style="width: 421px; height: 179px;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="../../Content/uploads/319e1bf6-9b79-4009-8108-c1d2ed77ffbb/85c232e7-33e8-49bb-acbe-374f5ad49361.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="209" /></td>
        <td style="width: 692px; height: 179px; vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="color: #626262;">

                <span style="color: #626262;">The United States&nbsp;</span>

                <input id="response[0]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #4363d8;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[0]_box" type="text" value="Constitution" data-id="0" />

                <span style="color: #626262;">&nbsp;has 27 amendments, of which the first&nbsp;</span>

                <input id="response[1]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #3cb44b;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[1]_box" type="text" value="10" data-id="1" />
                <input id="response[1]_box" style="border: 2px double #3cb44b;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[1]_box" type="text" value="BAD INPUT BAD INPUT" data-id="1" />
                <span style="color: #626262;">&nbsp;amendments are called the Bill of Rights.&nbsp; The purpose of the Bill of Rights is to provide specific freedoms to citizens and limit the power of the&nbsp;</span>

                <input id="response[2]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #e6194b;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[2]_box" type="text" value="government" data-id="2" />

                <span style="color: #626262;">.</span></div>

            <br style="color: #626262;" /><span style="color: #626262;">The United States Bill of Rights plays a central role in American law and government, and remains a fundamental symbol of the freedoms and culture of the nation. One of the original fourteen copies of the U.S. Bill of Rights is on public display at the National&nbsp;</span><input id="response[3]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #ffe119;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[3]_box" type="text" value="Archives" data-id="3" /><span style="color: #626262;">&nbsp;in Washington, D.C.</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Responses 1:

```
{false, 1, "The United States", false}
{true, 2, "has 27 amendments, of which the first", false}
{true, 3, "amendments are called the Bill of Rights. The purpose of the Bill of Rights is to provide specific freedoms to citizens and limit the power of the", false}
{true, 4, "The United States Bill of Rights plays a central role in American law and government, and remains a fundamental symbol of the freedoms and culture of the nation. One of the original fourteen copies of the U.S. Bill of Rights is on public display at the National", false}
{true, 5, "in Washington, D.C.", true}
```

HTML 2:

```
South <input id="response[0]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #4363d8;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[0]_box" type="text" value="FIB" data-id="0" /> is the largest provice in the Southern Hemisphere.
```

Responses 2:

```
{false, 1, "South", false}
{true, 2, "is the largest province in the Southern Hemisphere", true}
```

HTML 3:

```
<input id="response[0]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #4363d8;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[0]_box" type="text" value="FIB" data-id="0" /> Smith
```

Responses 3:

```
{true, 1, "Smtih", true}
```

HTML 4:

```
<span>John <input id="response[0]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #4363d8;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[0]_box" type="text" value="FIB" data-id="0" />
planted apples.</span>
```

Responses 4:

```
{false, 1, "John", false}

{true, 2, "Planted Apples", true}
```

HTML 5:

```
Smith <input id="response[0]_box" class="response" style="border: 2px double #4363d8;" contenteditable="false" disabled="disabled" name="response[0]_box" type="text" value="FIB" data-id="0" />
```

Responses 5:

```
{false, 1, "Smtih", false}
```

Originally, I was looking for any span nodes, which kind of made sense with the original HTML blob, however, as new requests come in, the original way quickly becomes unusable. It assumes too many things about the structure of the HTML blob coming in.

Where I've been tearing my hair out is how to re-structure the HtmlAgilityPack Search. Partly because we need to be aware of where in the HTML blob the node lives, and we also need to be able to combine text nodes if there are multiple between an input node.

What I think makes sense is to search for each input node.

Get all the inner text before the input node, if any, and make that into a response.

Then go to the next input node, get all the inner text between it and the previous input node, rinse and repeat.

Then do a final search for the inner text of the last node following the last input, and create a response, if it exists.

```
void Main()
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    var htmlToLoad = "Short <input id=\"response[0]_box\" class=\"response\" style=\"border: 2px double #4363d8;\" contenteditable=\"false\" disabled=\"disabled\" name=\"response[0]_box\" type=\"text\" value=\"FIB\" data-id=\"0\" /> item";

    doc.LoadHtml (htmlToLoad);

    var tableNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//span");
    var answerNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//input[@class='response']");

    if (tableNode == null)
    {
        htmlToLoad = string.Format ("<span> {0} </span>", htmlToLoad);
        doc.LoadHtml (htmlToLoad);
        tableNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//span");
    }

    var responses = new List<Response>();

    for (var i = 0; i < tableNode.Count; i++)
    {
        var response = new Response
        {
            isLeading = false,
            ResponseId = i,
            LeadingStem = tableNode [i].InnerText,
            isLagging = false
        };

        responses.Add (response);

        if (i == tableNode.Count - 2)
        {
            ++i;
            Console.WriteLine (answerNodes [i - 2].GetAttributeValue ("value", ""));
            Console.WriteLine (tableNode [i].InnerText);

            var laggingResponse = new Response
            {
                isLeading = true,
                ResponseId = i,
                LeadingStem = tableNode [i].InnerText,
                isLagging = true
            };
        }

        else if (i < answerNodes.Count - 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (answerNodes [i].GetAttributeValue ("value", ""));
        }
    }
}



public class Response
{
    public bool isLeading { get; set; } //set to true only if there was an input detected after the last response was read
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string LeadingStem { get; set; }
    public bool isLagging { get; set; } //set to true only if it's the final text node, and has no input after it
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be much easier using regex to walk the document, and using HtmlAgilityPack to read attributes as needed. This also allowed a way of reworking the response class to something much simpler than the previous implementation.

```
        var pattern = @"(<input)(.*?)(>)";
        var options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;

        var input = item.GetHtmlInput();
        var matStems = new Queue<Tuple<string, int>>();
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options);

        var currentStringPosition = 0;

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            if(m.Index == 0)
            {
                var leadingStem = new Tuple<string, int>("", -1);
                matStems.Enqueue(leadingStem);
            }

            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(m.Value);
            var inputElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input").LastOrDefault();
            var inputResponseId = inputElement.Attributes["data-id"].Value;

            var endingIndex = m.Index + m.Length;
            var stemLength = m.Index - currentStringPosition;
            var stemContent = input.Substring(currentStringPosition, stemLength);

            var stemToAdd = new Tuple<string, int>(stemContent, Convert.ToInt32(inputResponseId));

            matStems.Enqueue(stemToAdd);
            currentStringPosition = endingIndex;

            if (endingIndex != input.Length) continue;
            var laggingStem = new Tuple<string, int>("", -1);
            matStems.Enqueue(laggingStem);
        }

        if (currentStringPosition < input.Length)
        {
            var stemContent = input.Substring(currentStringPosition);
            var stemToAdd = new Tuple<string, int>(stemContent, Convert.ToInt32(-1));
            matStems.Enqueue(stemToAdd);
        }
```

Consuming items from the queue could then be done as follows:

```
        while (matStems.Any())
        {
            var stem = MaterialStems.Dequeue();
            item.WriteStem(stem.Item1);
            var response = item.GetResponses().ElementAtOrDefault(stem.Item2);
            if(response != null) item.WriteResponse(response);
        }
```